# Error executing javascrit file through nashorn jjs

Tags: scripts, java, environment-variables, javascript

I can execute jjs on bash

```
$ jjs
jjs>
```

but I can not execute script

```
$ ./executable.js
/usr/bin/env: jjs -scripting: No such file or directory
```

**executable.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env jjs -scripting
print(
"Arguments (${$ARG.length})");
for each (arg in $ARG) {
  print("- ${arg}")
}
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Nashorn requires certain syntax, change your script for (check the shebang!):

```
#!/usr/bin/jjs -fv

print("Arguments: " + $ARG);
print($ARG);     // arg1, arg2
print($ARG[0]);  // arg1
```

And when executing, you can use:

```
jjs -scripting asdf.js -- arg1 arg2
```

Will print:

```
Arguments: arg1,arg2
arg1,arg2
arg1
```